# How does the Dzhanibekov Effect change if replaced with a propeller?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, orbital-motion, aerodynamics

Every explanation and example uses a t-bar. But what if the "bar" was a propeller? I can understand there being no difference if it's a vacuum, but I would think the aerodynamics would change in a gaseous environment.

Comment: Depends on the shape of the propeller, the effect is due to moments of inertia being unique, but a propeller shape might not satisfy that condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the motion of the object that you describe will be to some degree different from the motion of an object where only the Dzhanibekov effect is at play.

The thing is: that does not change the Dzhanibekov effect itself. When you give the arms of the T-bar a shape that is designed to grip the air then you are not changing the Dzhanibekov effect, you are introducing additional effect, arising from the blades gripping the air.

The Dzhanibekov effect does not involve aerodynamics. The motion pattern arises from momentum being relocated internally.

That is, the Dzhanibekov effect is dependent on the object being rigid. In the case of a non-rigid object: during the motion the object will flex in response to whatever instantaneous (internal) stress there is, and that flexing will dissipate kinetic energy. Kinetic energy will then dissipate until there is no longer opportunity to dissipate energy. Going back to the rigidity; when the object has very good rigidity there is from the start negligable opportunity to dissipate energy, and then the motion pattern of the Dzhanibekov effect keeps going, with the continuous internal relocation of momentum.

Answer (score 2):

A T-handle has three distinct mass moment of inertia values (indicated below in red, green and blue directions)

[image: fig1]

As you notice, about the *z*-axis (blue) the MMOI value of $47\;{\rm kg}\,{\rm mm}^2$ is the intermediate one (the middle value), ($26.8 < 47.1 < 71.7$).

When spun about this axis, the object is in an unstable equilibrium where a small deviation in the rotation axis, builds up over time and causes the object to flip.

This is because there is only one plane of symmetry (the *xz* plane).

If you use a two-blade propeller, the same situation will exist, causing an unstable rotation. This is not an issue with an aircraft as the propeller shaft keeps the rotation axis fixed, and the restoring moments required to keep everything aligned are negligible.

If you use a three-blade or more propeller, then there is axial symmetry about the *z* axis and the MMOI value is equal about *x* as about *y* so the spin axis is stable.

Comment: You use the word 'unstable'; I submit that on the whole that is a wrong way of thinking about it. In the available demonstrations the object is chosen for its property of exhibiting the most vivid Dzhanibekov effect possible. However, if you would use an object with the three moments of inertia close together (but still no two of them the same) then the same motion pattern occurs, but way slower, extending over many more revolutions of the object, with regular period. Source: Nicholas Mecholsky [Analytic formula for the Geometric Phase of an Asymmetric Top](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03867)

Comment: @Cleonis - Unstable here has the standard meaning of a small perturbation causing a large-scale effect in the long term. There is no mention of how quickly this happens.

Comment: Well, the expression 'small perturbation' is not applicable either. A Dzhabenikov cycle is regular. That is, in the absence of any form of dissipation of energy the object will keep going through the cycles with constant periodicity. There is no involvement of some form of destabilization.  The closest comparison, it would appear, is a linear combination of multiple cycles, each with different period, such that there is an overall longer duration cycle where there is a regularly recurring interval of large amplitude motion when the amplitudes of the contributing cycles line up constructively.

Comment: @Cleonis - I disagree. A parallel rotation about the mid-MMOI axis will continue indefinitely without flipping, and only with a small perturbation in the rotation axis the effect becomes evident.

Comment: @Cleonis - thank you for the paper. I will pour over it. It reminds me of NASA paper from the 60's where they explore the stability of _almost_ axisymmetric objects (like rockets) when they are spinning.

Comment: David Brown (Youtube channel: physics unsimplified) offers extensive discussion of the [Dzhanibekov effect](https://youtu.be/NJLdW4DHRcA). (Two separate videos) David Brown offers the following comparison: a pendulum with a rod, free to swing through a full 360 degrees. Let the swing be perfectly frictionless. Release from standstill at 179.9 degrees. The pendulum will linger at that position, but it cannot **not** start swinging. Put release at 179.99 degrees, or 179.999, etc.; the pendulum will linger correspondingly longer, but eventually it will always swing, never requiring perturbation.